# How to use cpanspec to include all dependent packages

Tags: fedora, cpan, rpm

I wanted to build an RPM from cpan library. I used below command to build the RPM. It says few other packages are needed. When I try to install other packages the tail continues. Is there a smart way to that I can ask the cpanspec to include all the dependencies? (I am working on fedora 15)

```
[root@server cpanspec]# cpanspec LWP::Protocol::https -p abc --build
error: Failed build dependencies:
    perl(IO::Socket::SSL) >= 1.54 is needed by perl-LWP-Protocol-https-6.04-1.fc15.noarch
    perl(LWP::UserAgent) >= 6.04 is needed by perl-LWP-Protocol-https-6.04-1.fc15.noarch
    perl(Mozilla::CA) >= 20110101 is needed by perl-LWP-Protocol-https-6.04-1.fc15.noarch
    perl(Net::HTTPS) >= 6 is needed by perl-LWP-Protocol-https-6.04-1.fc15.noarch
/usr/bin/rpmbuild exited with value 1
```

Comment: From the looks of [this documentation](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Perl/cpanspec), cpanspec should fetch dependencies for you.  Which version of cpanspec are you using?

Comment: I am using cpanspec version 1.78. fedora 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the flag --follow. This option process build dependencies